# Errors on "apt-get update" after trying to install "Ubuntu TV"

Tags: ubuntu-tv

Whenever I run `apt-get update` I get this output:

```
Hit:1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                      
Hit:3 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                                                 
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]                                                                          
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/appgrid/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/test3/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                            
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                           
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                             
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                 
Ign:12 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.10  InRelease                                       
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease                             
Hit:15 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.10  Release        
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial Release    
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial Release
Hit:7 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb InRelease              
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                                   
  404  Not Found
Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                                    
Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages                                                                     
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US                                                                
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                                                                   
Ign:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                            
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                               
Err:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                       
  404  Not Found
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                        
Ign:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages                                                         
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US                                                    
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                                                       
Ign:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                                
Ign:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                                   
Fetched 94.5 kB in 7s (13.2 kB/s)                                                                                                                    
/usr/share/appgrid/appdata/helpers.py:9: PyGIWarning: Soup was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Soup', '2.4') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GLib, GObject, Soup
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 4CCA1EAF950CEE4AB83976DCA040830F7FAC5991 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg: Signature by key 3B068FB4789ABE4AEFA3BB491397BC53640DB551 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/u2t/bleedingedge/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/unity-2d-team/unity-2d-daily/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have been trying to install Ubuntu TV following this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTV/Contributing

and it's not getting installed. 
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using 12.04 or another version ?
Just curious cause the instructions say "At this time Ubuntu TV is only supported on Ubuntu 12.04. If you do not have 12.04 and would still like to help out we suggest that you use a virtual machine for now. "

Comment: actually i have v16. 
That sums up the problem i guess.

Comment: is there any other way to "cast" youtube to my pc? (Not using youtube.com/tv)

Comment: how can i get rid of all the errors on update?